# What makes a server side web technology browser compatible or incompatible?

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

What makes a server side web technology (like classic ASP, ASP.NET Web Forms, MVC and so on..) browser compatible or incompatible? Is it just the HTML which is generated makes all the difference or some more things?

In theory, if I write a code which generates HTML markup text (along with required javascript etc.) which all modern browsers support and give it back to browser to render, will that make my code compatible with modern browser?

Comment: Where did you read about "server side web technology browser incompatibility"? never heard of that, and what you say makes sense

Comment: The only thing that makes browsers incompatible, is the fact that some of those browser ignore standards. IE and Edge for example are known for having comp. issues with the CSS standard. But this is more of a frontend problem. ASP.NET/PHP/... don't have incompatbilities simply because they're in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the HTML you generate is all the browser cares about. It doesn't care whether it is coming straight from an HTML file, or being generated via a script or programming language. All of that processing happens on the server, and then the HTML stream is presented to the user's browser.